# Scanning for network devices

Tags: ios, swift, networking, swift3, network-scan

I want to scan for all devices in the local network. Then I want to further check if the discovered devices respond on a specific port, say #4000 for example. All that should happen on an iPad preferably using Swift (version 3).

Should I use a library for that job?

[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/BrowsingForServices.html) document didn't help me and sadly I cannot find useful information on the internet.

Edit: I want to know how can you implement this in Swift/iOS libraries. Are there any examples, libraries, core classes where I should start?

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: @ron Yes I know, but I want to find an answer to the question how to do this in the iOS way. As I doubt I need a library for this, I hesitated to put it on software recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may know what you are trying to ask. Your device sees the router, but doesn't know who is connected.

Read about multicast IP and broadcast IP, which is usually the highest IP address in your subnet.

Example: 192.168.1.255

As example, you make all devices listen on broadcast/multicast IP. To discover, you send a UDP message to that IP. Your router, if not configured otherwise, will forward that to the other devices.

This message can be something like "I am Mr. John, Reply to me at this Port".

That is the general idea

Comment: Yes, that is my question. :) How can you implement this in Swift/iOS libraries? Are there any examples, libraries, core classes where I should start?

Comment: I am not Swift expert, but at least you can search for specific thing now!

Comment: @felixd, "_Are there any examples, libraries, core classes where I should start?_" that is the part that is off-topic here.